# What is the difference among "spend doing something", "spend on doing something" and "spend in doing something"?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, difference

What is the difference among "spend something doing something", "spend something on doing something" and "spend something in doing something"? Can I use "spend something to do something"?
For example, are the following sentences correct, and are there any differences in meaning?

1. I spend my free time reading books.
2. I spend my free time on reading books.
3. I spend my free time in reading books.
4. I spend my free time to read books.

Comment: (1) and (3) are correct. (4) is not idiomatic English. As for (2), we speak of spending money _on_ something, but not usually time. I can't give you a reason why - it's just how the language works.

Comment: To spend time or money on [something]//to spend time [verb with ing] + object.